# How to create swipeable view only to half?

Tags: android

I tried searching but can't seem to find a swipeable view that can only swipe only half.

Here is an example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unl6o.png).

I tried creating two pages (in a tab) that contains image 1 and image 2, but the animation is having two stars when you are in mid-swipe.

Cheers.

Edit: found a working example.  I will just try mimicking this one.

https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ViewPager to serve for this purpose and customise them in a way so that one ViewPager change the other. In this way, I will give a feel that it is being swiped from half.

Comment: Hi, I used ViewPager for this, hence my question, I don't know how to customise them like you said.